# Django trying to add "_id" to the primary key OneToOne column

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

Just started Django.
I have 2 models. Radusergroup and expiration. username is primary key on Radusergroup and a OnetoOne Field in expiration with primary_key=True. Django is trying query for username_id in expiration model although the field itself is username only.

When I dont explicitly define Managed=False it also tries to change the username field in expiration table from the database to username_id as well.
What am I doing wrong here ?

```
class Radusergroup(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=64,primary_key=True)
    groupname = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    priority = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        managed = False


class expiration(models.Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(Radusergroup,on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='username', primary_key=True)
    expiration = models.DateTimeField()
    class Meta:
        managed = False
```

```
python .\manage.py shell
>>> help(expiration())
Help on expiration in module panel_app.models object:

class expiration(django.db.models.base.Model)
 |  expiration(*args, **kwargs)
 |
 |  expiration(username, expiration)
 |
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      expiration
 |      django.db.models.base.Model

 |      builtins.object
 |
 |  Methods defined here:
 |
 |  expiration = <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object>
 |  get_next_by_expiration = _method(self, *, field=<django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField: expiration>, is_next=True, **
kwargs)
 |
 |  get_previous_by_expiration = _method(self, *, field=<django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField: expiration>, is_next=Fals
e, **kwargs)
 |
 |  username_id = <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object>
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What don't you understand? A relationship field refers to the entire related object; the underlying database field stores the ID of that object.

Comment: read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#database-representation)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks dirkgroten for pointing me to the right direction.
Adding db_column solved my problem

```
class expiration(models.Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(Radusergroup,on_delete=models.PROTECT, to_field='username',db_column="username" , primary_key=True)
```